# Is there a way to apply styling according to the order classes are applied?

Tags: html, css

If We do something like this in our `css`

```
.class01.class02.class03{ background-color: lavenderblush; }

.class03.class01.class02{ background-color: brown; }
```

and this in our html

```
<article class="class01 class02 class03"></article>
<article class="class03 class01 class02"></article>
```

the 2nd rule will be applied to both elements.  Is there a way to make these rules apply according to the order?

Comment: Maybe read this? https://css-tricks.com/the-order-of-css-classes-in-html-doesnt-matter/

Comment: I would strongly recomend you NOT to set your styles like this. This will be a maintenance disaster, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

It won't work because: [Order of CSS classes in HTML doesn't matter](https://css-tricks.com/the-order-of-css-classes-in-html-doesnt-matter/) but there is a way using [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
article[class="class01 class02 class03"]{ background-color: lavenderblush; }

article[class="class03 class01 class02"]{ background-color: brown; }
```

```html
<article class="class01 class02 class03">Test1</article>
<article class="class03 class01 class02">Test2</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I don't suggest doing it as classes aren't meant to be used like this, but I guess there's at least one way for accomplishing the desired result...

```css
article {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

article[class*="class01 class02 class03"] {
  background: lavenderblush;
}

article[class*="class03 class01 class02"] {
  background: brown
}
```

```html
<article class="class01 class02 class03"></article>
<article class="class03 class01 class02"></article>
```

So we're checking that the class contains the exact provided substring, while the wildcard allows the class list to contain other classes before and after as well. When an exact match is needed we could use `article[class="class03 class01 class02"]`.

Comment: Wild card `*` doesn't care about the order. OP is interested in the order of classes. `class=` or `class^=` will care about the order

Comment: @TJ When you write out part of the class like I did, then the order matters. Meaning that class01 must preceed class02 exactly like in other answers, but this allows others classes to be present on the article as well.

Comment: `<article class="class05 blue class03 class01` will match and order failed

Comment: I made my answer more relevant to the original provided example, but I've kept the wildcard. This allows to also match articles when other non-relevant classes proceed or follow the class list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[class="class1 class2 class3"]** attribute in the css by specifying the order of classes you want.

```css
article[class="class01 class02 class03"] {
    background-color: lavenderblush;
}

article[class="class03 class01 class02"] {
    background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<article class="class01 class02 class03">text</article>
<article class="class03 class01 class02">text</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is no: it is not possible to the normal common notation. Only the trick using the attribute selector as given in the other answers does work on the first look. But head up: it is not as easy as it seems.

**EXPLANATION: HOW IT WORKS**

Indeed you are able to calculate/controll it.

In HTML/CSS wins the element/class/id construct with highest specifity. It is a slightly complex ranking on the first view but if only used classes it is not as complicated.

For **class construction `a.b.c`** the specifity counts:

- special combination off this three classes which overrides i.e. background setting of `a.b.x`
- the total count of used classes what means this three classes overwrite i.e. background setting off `a.b`
- **NOTE ATTRIBUTE SELECTOR:** One attribute selector counts as one class. So, if you have an attribute seletor `[class="a b c"]` it lose against `c.b.a` noted on another place in your stylesheet.
- Order in HTML does not count for the specifity: `a b c` is the same combination and the same number of classes as `c b a`.
- If a class construct (combination) with the same specifity noted twice in a CSS i.e. `a.b.c: red` and `c.b.a: green` the last notation overwrites the notation done before.

Some thinking:

Importand: the decision which concept is used to style a page is up to the coder himself!!! But even the attribute selector is a chance to realize that concept it is not the intendend way to use CSS. I asume using the rules of specifity in the intended css way could be a better/more intuitive way to control the design.

---

*Links with information about specifity:*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
https://specifishity.com/